# Way to blur only the QRCode in image with Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, qr-code, zbar

I was building a Processing Images API, which is composed by 3 steps, remove the image background,
blur the QRCode if found it and change the background to White.

At first worked using some standard images with QRCode.

But in the meantime, some images began to blur other areas which doesn't have QRCode.

If someone know how to do it properly, i'll be grateful.

My code (func) :

```
def blur_qrcode(path, image : Mat):
    is_qrcode = pyzbar.decode(image=image, symbols=[pyzbar.ZBarSymbol.QRCODE])

#     # if there is a QR code
    if is_qrcode:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        _, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 196, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        for contour in contours:
            if cv2.contourArea(contour) > 100:  # Adjust if needed
                x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
                qrcode_area = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

                qrcode_gray = cv2.cvtColor(qrcode_area, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                _, qrcode_thresh = cv2.threshold(qrcode_gray, 196, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

                qrcode_contours, _ = cv2.findContours(qrcode_thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
                qrcode_mask = np.zeros(qrcode_gray.shape, dtype=np.uint8)

                for qrcode_contour in qrcode_contours:
                    if cv2.contourArea(qrcode_contour) > 10:  # Adjust if needed
                        cv2.drawContours(qrcode_mask, [qrcode_contour], -1, 255, -1)

                qrcode_blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(qrcode_area, (25, 25), 0)
                image[y:y+h, x:x+w] = qrcode_blurred
        
        file_name = secrets.token_hex(8) + '_blurred.png'
        full_path = os.path.join(path, file_name)
        if cv2.imwrite(full_path, image):
            return full_path
        else:
            return ''
    else:
        return 'no_qrcode'
```

Using `opencv` `pyzbar`

Expected to Only blur the QRCode.

Comment: One way is to create a mask of the region for the QR code as white and everywhere else black. Then blur the whole image. Then use the mask to select the blurred image where the mask is white and the original image where the mask is black

Comment: See normalized convolution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59685140/python-perform-blur-only-within-a-mask-of-image and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594993/gradient-mask-blending-in-opencv-python